# mysql cluster: how to connect

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-18.04, mysql-cluster

I can not connect to my mysql cluster. I followed this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04
I tried connecting with workbench and mysql command to both data nodes and managment nodes on both 3306 and 1186 but I can cont connect to anywhere. Firewall is disabled on all machines. I created new user which can connect from anywhere but still no luck. Cluster works according to the test in the tutorial. To which node and port should i try to connect? Or is something missing in that tutorial?

Comment: The nodes are on private IPs. Are you connecting within the same network or from outside.  (You can not connect from outside). If you are inside the network, 
have you tried telnet command to one of the nodes to see you can connect?  

telnet node.ip.here 3306

Comment: @nafooesi thank you so so much, was stuck on it for last 4 hours and your suggestion really helped. I tried telnet command and it spit out connection refused so I started googling and my problem was that my cluster was not binding to right address. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it thanks to [nafooesi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1272760/nafooesi). For everyone that has same problem I did this.

Tried on my managment node `telnet localhost 3306` .
It said connection refused.
I have edited /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.
`sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
Find  bind-address = 127.0.0.1 and rewrite it with bind-address = ip.of.managment.node

And with workbench and programming languages you connect to your managment node not data nodes as i previously thought.

Thanks once again [nafooesi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1272760/nafooesi).

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be able to help. Service address binding addresses another aspect of security. The default is always binding to local ip 127.0.0.1, so that only local connection can be made (on the same node).